# MYSQL 1215 cannot add foreign constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So I don't know why i cant add the foreign constraint in the table ORDER_LINE, i made sure all the types are correct. Please help, it keeps on giving me the error

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer (
    Customer_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Customer_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Customer_Age INT UNIQUE,
    Customer_Address VARCHAR(255),
    Customer_City VARCHAR(255),
    Customer_State VARCHAR(50),
    Customer_Zip VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sales_order (
    Order_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Order_date DATE,
    Customer_ID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(Order_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID) ON DELETE     
    CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (
    Product_ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Product_Description VARCHAR(255),
    Product_Finish VARCHAR(50),
    Standard_Price DECIMAL,
    Product_Line_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Product_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDER_LINE   (
    Order_ID int,
    Product_ID int,
    Ordered_Quantity int,
    PRIMARY KEY(Order_ID, Product_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Order_ID) REFERENCES Sales_order(Order_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(Product_ID) REFERENCES Products(Product_ID)
);
```

Comment: Are you running all these `CREATE TABLE ...` queries in one shot? Have you tried running them individually?

Comment: Also try to use different names for your foreign keys and primary keys, FK_Order_ID and PK_Order_ID

Comment: @CrazyCucumber Yup :(

Comment: @noobcoder Which table Could you identify which of the two foreign keys gives error? Try creating it without of the of fk and see if only 1 gives error or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because [primary key columns are made `NOT NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/silent-column-changes.html), so your `ON DELETE SET NULL` is trying to set an invalid value.

EDIT: In fact, I just tested and that does seem to be the issue -- it creates the table if I remove either the `SET NULL` or the primary key.

Comment: oooh you're referring to that set null.. I realized that because it was a primary key, it couldnt be null..... Thanks i didnt read youre answer properly..

Comment: I've edited my answer to be a little more specific.  Is it working for you now?

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle showing that changing to `ON DELETE CASCADE` fixes the problem:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07206ac.

Comment: Thank you :) Ive done this on Oracle DB where you can set ON DELETE SET NULL to a composite Primary key, but MySQL doesn't seem to allow this. Thanks alot for the insight.